# imagemap in Safari

Tags: sharepoint, safari, imagemap

I originally did this with images being floated but in IE I was getting this 1px separation between all the images for some reason.  It seemed easier to use 1 image and throw an imagemap over it.  Now I find out that in Safari the imagemap doesn't work.  Only 6% of our traffic but that unfortunately includes or Executive VP's home computer.  D'oh.

I cannot figure out why this wont work despite all my searching.  Please help!

There are 4 images with imagemaps - all have unique IDs.  There's lots of bonus code in there thanks to Sharepoint not caring about what I tell it.

http://www.worldvision.ca/About-Us/financial-information/Pages/2011-annual-report-focus.aspx

```
<img src="images/footer_focus_development.jpg" alt="" style="margin-left:-100px; margin-top:-5px; position:relative;" usemap="#imgmap2012127151844"  border="0"/>
<map id="imgmap2012127151844">
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="403,197,482,215" href="http://childview.worldvision.ca/childview/en/?page_id=250p=1183" target="" />
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="446,431,531,447" href="http://childview.worldvision.ca/childview/en/?p=74" target="" />
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What is the actual problem? It looks different in Safari, but all links seem to be working for me. Could you post some more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to @moontear and thanks for the help.  I managed to fix this but wasn't able to post the answer for 8 hours :(

So, turns out that you need to also specify the NAME attribute for the  and not just an ID.

Silly!